# How to iterate through a directory and apply python script to multiple subfolders (not files) in that directory?

Tags: python, loops, directory-structure, os.walk, python-os

I am using a programme which converts dicom files stored in two different folders (input folders) to nifti format and saves them to a third folder (output folder). At the moment this programme requires me to manually specify the filepaths for these three folders.

I have a directory with multiple patients/subjects in it, each containing the two (input) folders. The third (output) folder does not exist but I have added os.makedirs to the above programme so it creates it.

I would like to create a script that can automate this process so that I don't have to manually specify the 3 filepaths for each patient. I want it to take each and every patient folder in the directory and apply the above - i.e read the dicom files in the two input folders for each patient, and then save the converted nifti files to a new folder for that specific patient.

```
#Importing libraries and modules:
import os
from dcmrtstruct2nii import dcmrtstruct2nii, list_rt_structs

#Next I want to create a for-loop that will walk through the directory patient folders/subfolders
#and that can then feed into the below section to automatically specify the RTstructdicom folder, the imagedicom folder
#and that can create a new folder called "Nifti" that can store the output.

for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('/Users/sh/Drive/folderC'):

    #**This is where I'm stuck**
   
#This next section will create the specified outputfolder e.g. 'Nifti',
#Then load the RTstruct dicom from the specified folder, 
#Then load the images dicoms from the specified folder,
#Then convert both to Nifti files saved in the specified output folder

RTstructdicom = ('/Users/sh/Drive/folderC/patient001/subfolder 1/RTSTRUCT_20210124_205145/RTSTRUCT/RTSTRUCT_20210124_205145.dcm')
imagedicoms = ('/Users/sh/Drive/folderC/patient001/subfolder 1/10022/DICOM')
outputfolder = ('/Users/sh/Drive/folderC/patient001/subfolder 1/10022/NIFTI')

print(list_rt_structs(RTstructdicom))
os.makedirs(outputfolder)
dcmrtstruct2nii(RTstructdicom, imagedicoms, outputfolder )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you want to do with each these multiple subfolders.

I hope this example will get you started.

I did my best to

- create an example directory tree
- iterate through it with `os.walk`
- do something to a particular subfolder

I suggest learning about the `Path` object from the `pathlib`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use

I wanted to copy the contents of a subdirectory so I imported shutil.

This is the sample tree I created:

```
folderC
├── patient001
│   └── subfolder 1
│       └── RTSTRUCT_085211_328790
│           └── RTSTRUCT
│               └── RTSTRUCT_085211_328790
│                   └── RTSTRUCT_085211_328790.dcm
├── patient002
│   └── subfolder 2
│       └── RTSTRUCT_958381_489352
│           └── RTSTRUCT
│               └── RTSTRUCT_958381_489352
│                   └── RTSTRUCT_958381_489352.dcm
└── patient003
    └── subfolder 3
        └── RTSTRUCT_731792_968907
            └── RTSTRUCT
                └── RTSTRUCT_731792_968907
                    └── RTSTRUCT_731792_968907.dcm
```

I then used the following code to to something to some particular subfolders:

﻿

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

for root, dirnames, _ in os.walk("folderC"):
    root_path = Path(root)
    for dirname in dirnames:
        dir_path = root_path / dirname
        # Use conditionals at this point to select which directory you want to work with.
        # For example.
        # make a destination folder in all folders with "subfolder" in the name
        if "subfolder" in dir_path.name:
            destination = (dir_path / "10022" / "NIFTI")
            destination.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
        # An example that copies the files from the deepest "RTSTRUCT_xxxx_xxxx" folder
        # to the destination
        if "RTSTRUCT_" in dir_path.name and dir_path.parent.name == "RTSTRUCT":
            shutil.copytree(dir_path, destination, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

This is the result. You can see the files from the "RSTRUCT_xxx_xxxx" directory is in the nearly created one inside of the "subfolder x" directory.

```
folderC
├── patient001
│   └── subfolder 1
│       ├── 10022
│       │   └── NIFTI
│       │       └── RTSTRUCT_085211_328790.dcm
│       └── RTSTRUCT_085211_328790
│           └── RTSTRUCT
│               └── RTSTRUCT_085211_328790
│                   └── RTSTRUCT_085211_328790.dcm
├── patient002
│   └── subfolder 2
│       ├── 10022
│       │   └── NIFTI
│       │       └── RTSTRUCT_958381_489352.dcm
│       └── RTSTRUCT_958381_489352
│           └── RTSTRUCT
│               └── RTSTRUCT_958381_489352
│                   └── RTSTRUCT_958381_489352.dcm
└── patient003
    └── subfolder 3
        ├── 10022
        │   └── NIFTI
        │       └── RTSTRUCT_731792_968907.dcm
        └── RTSTRUCT_731792_968907
            └── RTSTRUCT
                └── RTSTRUCT_731792_968907
                    └── RTSTRUCT_731792_968907.dcm
```

There are some simple examples in the Python documentation as well: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Sorry if I didn't make the OP clear. What I would like to do with the subfolders is to get them to plug into the conversion tool. At the moment I am needing to manually type the pathnames into the code - e.g. stating where to look for RTstructdicom, imagedicoms and outputfolder. What I would like to do is create a code that can automate this for every patient.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@dmmfll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913726/dmmfll), you can modify the script to iterate over each patient's folder, identify the input folders, and create an output folder for the NIfTI files. The loop will walk through each patient directory, construct paths for RTstruct and image DICOMs, create a NIfTI folder, and then perform the conversion. So basically, the answer is to use os.walk to consider the whole hierarchy.

Should be something like this:

```
import os
from dcmrtstruct2nii import dcmrtstruct2nii

base_dir = '/Users/sh/Drive/folderC'

for patient_id in next(os.walk(base_dir))[1]:
    patient_path = os.path.join(base_dir, patient_id)
    rtstruct_path = os.path.join(patient_path, 'RTSTRUCT.dcm')
    image_dicoms_path = os.path.join(patient_path, 'DICOM')
    output_folder = os.path.join(patient_path, 'NIFTI')
    
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
    dcmrtstruct2nii(rtstruct_path, image_dicoms_path, output_folder)
```

Comment: I just noticed that you have a different structure of the RT struct file. Adjust it as follows:
rtstruct_files = [f for f in os.listdir(patient_path) if f.startswith('RTSTRUCT')]
rtstruct_path = os.path.join(patient_path, rtstruct_files[0]) if rtstruct_files else None